# how to use libcore icu code in third party apps

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I am developing an application where I will need to fetch the timezone list same as used by Zonepicker class in Android AOSP Settings apps code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-4.3.1_r1/src/com/android/settings/ZonePicker.java

The `zonepicker` uses `SettingsLib` which uses android `libcore` internally, I tried using the `libcore` library but not able to import in my Android Studio Project

Can anyone please tell me how to use this libcore library: `libcore.util` package

Comment: Do you need to get a list of available time zones rt?

Comment: yes but same as the way Settings app shows, showing timezones as per the region

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` to get the list of all the TimeZones available on your device.

You can try below code:-

```
public static SimpleAdapter constructTimezoneAdapter(Context context,
            boolean sortedByName, int layoutId) {
        final String[] from = new String[] {ZoneGetter.KEY_DISPLAYNAME, ZoneGetter.KEY_GMT};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        final String sortKey = (sortedByName ? ZoneGetter.KEY_DISPLAYNAME : ZoneGetter.KEY_OFFSET);
        final MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator(sortKey);
        final List<Map<String, Object>> sortedList = ZoneGetter.getZonesList(context);
        Collections.sort(sortedList, comparator);
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context,
                sortedList,
                layoutId,
                from,
                to);

        return adapter;
    }
```

Comment: I have used the same code but not able to import Zonegetter class, any idea how do I use this class

Comment: This solution is not equivalent to the timezones that the `ZoneGetter` class would return.